# Regular Expression for Range (2-16)

Tags: regex

I want to match a number between 2-16, spanning 1 digit to 2 digits.

Regular-Expressions.info [has examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) for 1 or 2 digit ranges, but not something that spans both:

> The regex `[0-9]` matches single-digit numbers 0 to 9. `[1-9][0-9]` matches double-digit numbers 10 to 99.

Something like `^[2-9][1-6]$` matches 21 or even 96!  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
^([2-9]|1[0-6])$
```

will match either a single digit between 2 and 9 inclusive, or a 1 followed by a digit between 0 and 6, inclusive.

Comment: Thank you! **Quick note**, if you don't need to match from beginning to end of string, or if you don't need to capture the group: `(?:[2-9]|1[0-6])`

Comment: @skplunkerin: If the string isn't anchored, then you end up matching stuff like `17` or `25`, because the match skips the `1` at the beginning or the `5` at the end, respectively. You pretty much have to anchor the string, whether at the beginning or at a non-word character, in order to limit the range.

Comment: @cHao aw, you're right! I forgot to mention that I was using this inside of another regex similar to: `'filename-prefix-(?:[2-9]|1[0-6])\.gz'`, making it so I didn't want `^` or `$` and I thought I'd comment for others. For my case I was safe to remove these anchors, but elsewhere it wouldn't be.

Comment: @cHao, how to write a RegEx for a range of real numbers? Like if suppose the range is 0-9999, the regex should accept 9783.9848294857. I was writing one for same, https://regex101.com/r/I9fwfJ/4 , but not able to solve, any help?

Comment: @ShravilPotdar: `(\.\d+)?` would match an optional fractional part.  For example, `^([2-9]|1[0-6])(\.\d+)?$` would match 2, 10, 16.999, etc. It gets slightly more complicated if the limit is like 4.25 rather than an integer.

Answer (score 9):

With delimiters (out of habit): `/^([2-9]|1[0-6])$/`

The regex itself is just: `^([2-9]|1[0-6])$`

Comment: The slashes are PHP specific and probably should be removed when someone's talking about a general regular expression.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: That's not at all PHP specific. It can be used in any language that lets you pick your delimiter.

Comment: Perl had them before PHP. In any case, they're not part of the expression, indeed. If your language requires you to use something like that then the person who asked can trivially add them.

Comment: @Billy many languages specify regex *literals* using slashes.

Comment: Not all languages need delimiters -- they can be passed a regex as a normal string.

Comment: @eldareathis: Okay, perhaps it exists in some other languages, but the fact of the matter is that they are not part of the regex. Given that the OP has not specifically identified the flavor he is using they should be omitted.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Which I went back and edited in. I didn't disagree with that, which is why I added the edit. That doesn't make my assertion in my previous comment any less correct, though.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Thank you. And I apologize if my previous statement came off as confrontational. I do understand your point, and I'm going to try to notice when I post regexes like that in the future. Using `/` has just gotten ingrained into my head at this point...

Answer (score 4):

### Use the python package [`regex_engine`](https://pypi.org/project/regex-engine/) for generating regular expressions for numerical ranges

You can install this package with `pip`.

```sh
pip install regex-engine
```

```py
from regex_engine import generator

generate = generator()
    
regex = generate.numerical_range(2, 16)
    
print(regex)
```

```
^([2-9]|1[0-6])$
```

You can also generate regexes for floating point and negative ranges.

```py
from regex_engine import generator

generate = generator()

regex1 = generate.numerical_range(5, 89)
regex2 = generate.numerical_range(81.78, 250.23)
regex3 = generate.numerical_range(-65, 12)
```

Comment: For 0..x integers, it has some pretty weird rules that can be hand-optimized rather heavily. But it's a good starting point. `numerical_range(0, 32)` gives you `^([0-9]|[2-2][0-9]|1[0-9]|3[0-2])$` instead of `^(\d|[12]\d|3[0-2])$`. It is super-weird to see `[2-2]` in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
^([2-9]|1[0-6])$
```

(**Edit:** Removed quotes for clarification.)

Comment: The quotes are specific to how the regex would be inserted into a programming environment, but should probably be removed when talking about regexes in the abstract.

Comment: Your regex "^[2-9]|1[0-6]$" is wrong, because the "|" separates the "^" to the first pattern and the "$" to the second one. You need parentheses here, e.g.: "^([2-9]|1[0-6])$"

Comment: Thanks again. I always check my answers on some tool, but in this case I was fooled by a simple test in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your input formatters with

```
inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter(
                      RegExp(
                          r'^([0-9]|[2-8][0-9]|1[0-9]|9[0-9]|[2-8][0-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|10[0-9]|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[2-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9][0-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|100[0-9]|500[0-0])$'),
                      allow: true,
                    )
                  ],
```

Answer (score -2):

(^[2-9]$|^1[0-6]$)

By specifying start and stop for each set of numbers you are looking for your regex won't also return 36, 46, ... and so on. I tried the above solution and found that this works best for staying within the range of 2-16.