# Regular expression for 1 or more

Tags: regex

What is the a regular expression to only allow whole numbers from 1 through 99? (including both 1 and 99)

Comment: What's the context? Why not compare the number directly? Also have a look at this similar question: [Regular Expression - Range (2-16)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451389/regular-expression-range-2-16) and [all of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regular+expression+number+range).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$
```

The `?` means that the previous token is optional.

The `^` and `$` are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start and end of the string respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Surely you mean

```
 [1-9][0-9]?
```